# Firebase - how to set properly writing access without showing the user's id?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, authorization

I have the following data structure:

```
cars: {
  $uid: {
     brand: "Brand here",
     model: "Model here etc"
   },
   $uid: {
     brand: "Another brand here",
     model: "Another model here etc"
   }
}
```

Anyone can read this data like: firebase.com/cars/uniqueIDHere.json   - it is a public API
firebase.com/cars.json - is not accessible.

The rules now are set like this:

```
"cars": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

I want to have the following authorization rule: Only the user that created the "car" should be able to edit / remove it.
With the rules that are in place now, I think all the users that are logged in can do that (if they know the car's $uid).
What rules can be in place so only the owner can "write". I know the rules like:

```
"$uid": {
   ".read": "true",
   ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
}
```

where the $uid is the uid of the user, but I do not want that, because it will be exposed in the public API url
What approach I can take? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to separate **users** and **cars**.

A structure like that :

```
root
 |
 +-- cars
 |     |
 |     +-- $carId
 |           |
 |           +-- brand: $brand
 |           |
 |           +-- model: $model
 |
 +-- users
 |     |
 |     +-- $userId
 |           |
 |           +-- cars
 |                 |
 |                 +-- $carId: true
```

And rules will be like :

```
{
    "rules": {
        "cars": {
            "$carId": {
                ".read": "true",
                ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child("cars").child($carId).val() === true" 
            }
        },
        "users": {
            "$userId": {
                ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $userId",
                ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $userId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```